# I need to move the background image of my element outside of the element. Is it possible using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, css, background-image

This is Hapenning-

[image]

I need this-

[image]

I need to move the background image(orange circle) of my element outside of the element. Is it possible using CSS or Javascript?
Due to the structure of the HTML, I can not take another element inside the div. Need to doi it using :after only if possible.

```
  .element:after {
        display: inline-block;
        content: "";
        height: 250px;
        width: 217px;
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ff9400;
        border-left: 1px solid #FF9400;
        z-index: 15;
        background: url('files/images/icon5.png') no-repeat;
        background-position: 100% 100%;
    }
```

Just need to move my icon5.png outside of the box of element.

Comment: Do you want it to remain visible? Or no?

Comment: Any sample html or what it looks like now vs what you want it to look like?

Comment: @Wes Foster Yes, I wish to keep it visible.

Comment: @stevenw00 There is a small image of 16x16 px. The size of the element is defined in the CSS code. I need to move it ouside of the elements box.

Comment: @hiteshkumar you're only showing CSS for `:after` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). There is nothing about the element itself.

Comment: moving the image to a negative left or negative top will move it outside the parent  , or... a left or top number bigger then the size of the parent will move it outside

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do. Define a background element which only contains your image. size it to whatever you need. and then you make a smaller element inside of it. The following is an example of what I mean:

```
<style>
#BACKGROUND {background: url("testimage.jpg");width:50px;height:50px;}
#OVERLAP {color:#000;padding:10px;}
</style>
<div ID="BACKGROUND">
<div ID="OVERLAP">
ABC
</div>
</div>
```

Here, I created a background (DIV) element that's 50 by 50 pixels and then inside of that, I created another (DIV) element specifically for text that overlaps the image starting at 10 pixels in as defined via the padding statement for the DIV with the ID of OVERLAP. if the image is still in the way after adjusting numbers, then you can edit the image to include white space and adjust the sizes (pixel values) accordingly.